# Angle between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the angle between these two vectors. I know how to find the angle of using the dot product over magnitude of both vectors. However, these two vectors are opposite to each other, creating an angle of 180 degrees and a dot product of -29. Is there a difference between column vectors and row vectors when using this formula?

v = <-5,2>   w = <5,-2>   (in column form)

What is going on?

Comment: The angle formula is  ${\cos \theta} = {{V\cdot W} \over{ ||V || ||W||}}$ which in your case is $-1$. The angle whose cosine is $-1$ is $180^\circ$. Sometimes it is written as $AB^T$ if $A,B$  are rows or as $A^TB$ if they are column vectors, or ...

Comment: No difference at all.

Comment: Public service announcement: please do not get in the habit of numerically computing the angle using $\arccos$. For 2D and 3D vectors use $\operatorname{atan2}( |u\times v|, u\cdot v).$

Comment: @user7530 -- why is that?

Comment: I had a feeling that there was no difference. I got stumped when I found out that the answer had to be in radians and not in degrees which led to my belief that I was in the wrong...

Comment: @bubba: The derivative of a function gives you how much an error in the argument is amplified into an error in the result; with that in mind check out the derivative of $\arccos(x)$ near $x=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
u&=(-5,2)^T\\v&=(5,-2)^T\\
\cos(\theta)&=\dfrac{u^Tv}{||u||\times ||v||}\\
&=\dfrac{-29}{\sqrt{29}\times \sqrt{29}}\\
&=-1\\
\implies \theta&=180
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, this is the answer I got, however it is wrong in my WebWork. I don't understand why though.

Comment: @DimitriTopaloglou What is "WebWork"?

Comment: WebWork is a common place where students across Universities do their assignments online.

Comment: Maybe they want the answer in radians?

Comment: Perhaps the answer is in radians... I'll give that a try.

Comment: Yup. That's possible. Give it a shot.

Comment: @user7530 yea, it is... I can't believe it lol